# How can I make emacs support javascript ES6 template string literals?

Tags: javascript, syntax-table

I want to use [ES6 template string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) e.g.:

```
`string text line 1
 string text line 2
 string text ${expression}`
```

However emacs doesn't recognize that their contents are a string, so syntax highlighting, indentation, etc. don't work. How can I tell emacs that backticks are string delimiters?

I'm using emacs version 24.5, and the built in `js-mode`.

Comment: What's your Emacs version and which JS major mode are you using?

Comment: @lunaryorn I edited to add the information, but tbh I only opened this question as a google-friendly way to provide the answer for other people. My answer below works for me, but stack overflow won't let me accept it yet. Hope I didn't waste your time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add backticks as a string delimiter to the `js-mode` syntax table like this:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?` "\"" js-mode-syntax-table)
```

More information [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable).

Answer (score 7):

For the record,  ES6 template string literals are supported out-of-the-box in [`js2-mode`](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode), complete with font-locking for the interpolated variables as well.

Answer (score 3):

Or you just wait for Emacs 25.1 to come out. It's fixed there.